# Can't center h1 tag in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, text-align

[image]I am a beginner web development student and I am having trouble centering the h1 text in my code. I am using the `text-align: center` property, but the text is not centering.

I am also having trouble getting equal space between the "pricing, features, and blog" menu and the "sign in" and "sign up" buttons.

I am using the `justify-content: space-between` property, but the space between the "pricing, features, and blog" menu and the buttons is less than the space between the buttons.

```css
body {
  background: url(BG.png);
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 72px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

p.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  gap: 56px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.cta {
  display: flex;
  gap: 56px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.cta > button {
  color: white;
  width: 122px;
  background-color: #091d57;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 52px;
  font-weight: 800;
  max-width: 632px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Maze</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;700;800&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <p class="logo">Maze</p>
      <div class="menu">
        <p>Features</p>
        <p>Pricing</p>
        <p>Blog</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cta">
        <p>Sign in</p>
        <button>Sign up</button>
      </div>
    </header>
    <h1>Upgrade your skills for a better future</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I attempted to center the h1 text and distribute space evenly between the buttons, but my efforts were unsuccessful.

I have also searched for solutions online, but I have been unable to find a solution.

Comment: h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 52px;
  font-weight: 800;
  max-width: 632px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin:0 auto;
}
on h1 tag just add margin:0 auto;

Comment: @SunnyParsana Yes now it works. Can you explain what my mistake was.

Comment: It's my pleasure sir

Comment: when you center tag want to then just add margin:0px auto; on css

Comment: If you're new to web development, here's a helpful tip for you when creating a navigation bar, it's a good practice to use lists for better structure and accessibility. You can achieve this by wrapping the list items in a <nav> tag.

Comment: @AlgoPro Ok. I will keep that in mind when making nav bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your h1, the text is actually centered. (try setting the `font-size: 16px` to test, You will notice that the text is actually centered within the bordered box).
But since you have set a `max-width:623px;` for the h1 and given a border, instead of having a full width now the width of your box is fixed, you can align the whole combination using CSS by setting margins auto on left and right.

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Which means `margin-left` is auto and `margin-right` is auto, which sets the whole box to the center.

*Coming to your Part-B* of the question. About having equal spacing between the menus items and buttons, the issue is:

You have own container for menus (wrapper with `class="menu"`) and a container (wrapper with a `class="cta"`), though within the containers of each of each of these, the space is equal, but on the whole header, we need to carefully place these items within the space available. Flexbox works with the space provided for items to be placed. So, you need to do this carefully as per the design.
(Could you provide the design for menus please)

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Yes on setting the font to 16px the text is centered (within the box). But it isn't centered with respect to the page. Why?

Comment: The reason is you have set a fixed width for your heading :) And in CSS we have a box-model, after setting the fixed width to the h1, it would be considered as a box having the content. Assume it is a parent container for the text and all the CSS applied will happen within that box.

With text-align:center; we are telling to center the text now w.r.t the outer box. 

If you remove the max-width; you will see that the text will again be centered. Because h1 is block level element and takes full width of the container. In which case the text will be centered w.r.t the full width div.

Comment: Do you also want the all the menus items and buttons to be equally spaced, Could you share the screenshot in the Question of how you want the menus to show up

Comment: I have added the picture to the post.

Comment: Sure, let me see and try to get it done for you.
But I am sharing a free resource for you to go through flexbox 

https://scrimba.com/learn/flexbox 

This is a interactive course of Scrima and it will be helpful :) 
Happy coding

Comment: I feel the Menus is somewhat correct, But I believe that you want the spacing between the menus items (features, pricing, and blog) to be same as the space b/w the Two buttons. 

Right? Is this the query.

And could you also tell the how much space is required in pixels ?